# The Groupon API - What is the difference between endAt and expiresAt?

Tags: json, api, groupon

There is a lot of data provided in the Groupon API, but I can't find information anywhere on what the different fields mean.

"endAt" and "expiresAt" is quite ambiguous to me. The time at which a deal is no longer valid is quite important to get it wrong is no option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing, but I think expireAt sometimes null because not every offer has expiration, but I think it’s better then endAt date when it’s not null. So something like this makes sense to me:

```
string endDate = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(deal.expiresAt)) ? deal.expiresAt : deal.endAt;
```